# Choosing platforms for a lightweight music project

Tags: .net, macos, html, audio

I've had this idea of a music project that I want to do. But I've been forced to think in new directions because of platforms. It needs to work on Windows, Mac and iPhones/iPad. And why not Unix as well.

So that made me rethink everything basically. I was thinking WPF at first, but that's a bit quirky on Mac and Linux. And you can't just have it work in iPads either. And Adobe Air/Flex could work, but that's based on Flash isn't it? Adobe just discontinued Flash? Meaning, not a good choice? Another option could be HTML 5, but are there any means of connecting to libraries via HTML 5? I probably need to use some kind of sound library to make it work. And the application needs to look perty as well as being fast. It's really a lightweight client application where the sound files are on a separate server. So, streaming from web/server as well as sound.

It's beginning to look like two separate projects, where development happens towards Windows and a separate project towards Mac/iPhone/iPad. But the best thing would being able to reuse the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/). You can use [Titanium Desktop](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop-application-development/) to build desktop apps
for Windows, Mac and Linux and use [Titanium Mobile](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/) for building iOS/Android app.

Also, Adobe did not discontinue Flash completely. They only discontinued Flash for mobile.

Answer (score 1):

What level of complexity are you thinking of?

You wrote in your tags that you also might think about .NET? Well that might be the way to go but if you want to use [Mono](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) for mobile platforms you have to pay.
But now you can even create nice looking and working OSX apps by using [monomac](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac).

Appcelerator is useful for simple projects but most likely not for a complex mobile application. It all depends on how complex you want to go.

Comment: Well, it might be a bit complex. It's a small lightweight client app really that streams sound files from a remote server(s) and places them in a timeline. In other words, multitracks. Kinda like garageband on the iPad

Comment: Will the app download the stream as audio from the server or can it preload the files before playing them back? (although that does not sound user friendly :) If you want to use audio streaming, I think, that it is rather a challenge than a walk in the park using .NET or, as proposed by André, QT. Especially if you need to time the playback on a millisecond base, which is needed to prevent phasing, I would recommend to go as low as possible. So, something like Appcelerator would already be out of the loop.

Comment: Interesting topic though. Maybe worth to be looked at using .NET.

Comment: The app could use some sort of cached mode I guess. But there needs to be a flag, to check if the content is newer then what is already on the device. And stream accordingly.I don't mind paying for middleware or API's. That's the least problem really. Price is no issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Qt (http://qt.nokia.com/) would probably the best multiple platform solution if you want to build some more complex application. It has a long time support for Mac/Windows/Linux and there are also some extensions in development – supposedly working – aiming android and iOS.

Comment: I also thought of QT but as the qt-iphone project isn't more than a one-man test project (that actually seems to successfully run on the device) I wouldn't bet on it covering Core Audio completely. Have a look [here](http://youtu.be/MjYJdi48B8Q)